# why Date.now() return a wrong value in node.js

Tags: javascript, date

In the case of high concurrency, `Date.now()` returns me a wrong answer with a value of `3101529602444`, witch means `'Fri Apr 13 2068 16:00:02 GMT+0800'`.

Comment: Happens in the browser console too.

Comment: "*In the case of high concurrency*": concurrency with what?